# RISC-V PMP instruction access fault when jumping to U mode

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

I am trying to use PMP on a 16-byte region to protect a specific memory region. However, I am getting an instruction access fault when jumping to U mode when the PMP configuration is enabled.

**Details:**

- My program starts in M mode and at some point jump to U mode using
  mret. I am not using virtual memory for this test.
- Memory region that I want to protect starts at 0x80020180.
- I set the pmpaddr0 to 0x20008061 (right shift 0x80020180 by 2 and
  make the last two digits 0b'01 to mark the 16-byte region).
- pmp0cfg is set to 0b'0001 1000 (NAPOT is used and read, write,
  execute is not permitted).
- I have a store operation that tries to store to 0x80020184 in U mode.
  But the code gives instruction access fault when jumping to the U
  mode.
- The first instruction in U mode is located at PC 0x800004c0,
  which should not match with the pmpaddr0.

I am trying to figure out why it is giving instruction access fault when jumping to U mode.
Could anyone please help me to understand what's happening?

I am running my code on Spike, I am seeing the same behavior on rocket-core simulation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question, posting as thin might help someone else.

It turns out I missed an important sentence in the spec about the PMP priority.

```
If no PMP entry matches an M-mode access, the access succeeds. If no PMP entry matches an
S-mode or U-mode access, but at least one PMP entry is implemented, the access fails.
```

So I had to add a second PMP entry to match all addresses in U mode and that solved the issue.